# Pan map in a single direction

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

My V2 Map has been set in a random position, with a random bearing from north (so the compass symbol is likely to be pointing anywhere, but probably not north).

I want to shift/pan the map directly up the screen as the user looks at it, a short distance.

This may be very simple or require some complex calculations with lats, longs and trigonometry.

But I'm struggling to find a solution that works whatever the angle and zoom level is.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved this by finding a position on the screen and converting it to a LatLng, and then panning the map to this position. It worked perfectly.

```
Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
Point p = new Point(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);
LatLng pos = projection.fromScreenLocation(p);
```